# Pointer to generic record

Tags: delphi, pointers, generics

Note that this is not a duplicate of [Pointer to generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793472/pointer-to-generic-type). It's a followup question.

I know it is possible to define a pointer to any generic type.
It just that Delphi makes it complicated. It was meant to be impossible, but due to a compiler bug the option slipped through.
This is what the linked question answers.

My question is:

**How do I define a pointer to a generic record without encapsulating it in a surrounding class?**

Example code:

```
TGenericRecord<T> = record
  Data: integer;
  Procedure SomeMethod; inline; <<<< inlining is vital here. 
end;
```

I want to get a type safe pointer to TGenericRecord.
I do **not** want to wrap the record in a surrounding class because in my experiments I've found that that disables the inlining.

How do I get a typesafe generic pointer to this record.

**Use case**

```
{class} function create(size: integer): PGenericRecord{<T>}
```

I want to be able to create records on the heap in addition to the stack.

Comment: You could declare `Type PT = ^T;` inside the record and use it as `var
  m: TMiniStack<Integer>.PT;` with `m := TMiniStack<Integer>.Create;`.

Comment: No it's not, because that question does A: not provide the answer and B: I already know how to make a pointer to operate within the generic type itself. I'm asking a specific followup question to the one you're referring to.

Comment: @LURD, I'm not interested in a ^T, I want a `^TMiniStack<T>`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read more thoroughly.

Comment: It does provide an answer as Barry clearly explains that it's not possible to declare a pointer to a generic type.

Comment: @stefan, yes but the thing is that **is** possible.

Comment: @Johan only inside another generic type. Which is what stefan is getting at.

Comment: @David Exactly, the question was about a function to return a pointer to the type the function was in - and that is just not possible, period. Johans workaround is using the compiler bug that Barry mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @Stefan Kind of sucks that the useful workaround is deemed a compiler bug....

Comment: @StefanGlienke, Luckily for all of us, that bug is now a feature and a very useful feature at that. See any answer/comment below. Without the bug/feature I would have to resort to using pointers and type unsafe casts. Now however with some boilerplate I can have full type safety.

Comment: @Johan I would have preferred correct pointer support for generic types instead of a bug that slipped through and then stayed inside but whatever... Or I would have used a class instead of dynamic allocation of a record.

Comment: I would use a class, but I want this stack to be created on the Stack. I just wanted to add Heap support as an option, in case the TMiniStack need to be able to grow larger than would be prudent on the stack. The Stack-stack is used for quick in-and-outs and trees (they don't go that deep) and the Heap-stack is used when a deeper stack is needed. There the stack size can be specified. Something which is clearly impossible with a Stack based stack. Because it is a barebones stack all calls are inlines and consist of the absolute minimal code to make a stack work. It made my tree code 2x faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet probably looks like this:

```
type 
  TMyStaticClass<T> = class
  public
    type
      TRec = record
        ....
      end;
      PRec = ^TRec;
  public
    class function NewRec: PRec; static;
  end;
```

I don't have a compiler handy to check whether or not this even compiles but I feel that it should.....

Comment: It compiles (after adding an Integer to the record and adding an implementation for NewRec and correcting the syntax error - `<T>` should be after the name, not after `class`).

Comment: I would have posted a similar solution. The only disadvantage is that you have to address this type as `TMyStaticClass<SomeType>.PRec` instead of a simple `PRec`. I guess one can create an alias, once `SomeType` is known.

Comment: @rudy I think that is unavoidable