# How do I speedup the copy of a generic array?

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics, copy

I have a simple array:

```
Myarray<T> = array[0..100] of T;
```

How do I copy this as fast as possible into another array. 
Note that the source is always a plain generic array and the dest can be a dynamic array. (but I doubt that matters).

I tried

```
move(Source[0], dest[0], count * sizeof(T));
```

But that does not play nice with managed types.

I'm hoping to get something faster than:

```
for i:= 0 to count -1 do D[i]:= S[i];
```

What options do I have?

**Background**
The array is part of a BTree structure and there is a lot of copying going on.
I need the speed.

Comment: Why do you hope that simple assignment can be improved upon? What problem does simple assignment have?

Comment: Not nearly as quick as the moves. I would like something in between.

Comment: But the moves don't work. Assignment does. In what way is it inefficient? I guess that this question will confuse because of all the code. You just want a better performing way to assign. I think you should ask that general question rather than presenting all the other code that we don't need to see. The root of your Q is the perf of assignment. Please could you ask about that. Many of your questions are like this where you present lots of extraneous detail that hides the nub of the question.

Comment: It has no problems, but I want it to be faster.

Comment: The moves only work on simple types, perhaps I should special case that occurance and do to loop for everything else.

Comment: Ok, will distill the question in a short sscce with timings.... Deleting the Q

Comment: I'm thinking of this Q (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547128/pointer-to-generic-record). Could be an excellent Q if boiled down to the core. Instead all the extraneous detail that is personal to you gets in the way of the Q. So much that it has many close votes. Here you could ask, "How can X := Y be speeded up?". You'd need a couple of examples with timings. That would be a good Q. As it is we have to wade through your code to find the heart of the matter.

Comment: What about [System.CopyArray()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.CopyArray)?

Comment: I really enjoy your questions, once I understand them! I think you've asked loads of really valuable questions, but they could be more so if they were tighter and more focused. I'm trying to encourage this in a constructive way (I hope)!!

Comment: @david Thanks yes the constructive part did come across on the first try. The focussing makes it more generally applicable and thus a better question.

Comment: @Lurd will do a test with copyarray. I had it in my head that copyarray only works with dynamic arrays, but the docs do not say it does. Will test it and give feedback.

Comment: If your type T contains dynamic arrays, the refcounts will not be updated with `CopyArray()`, but pure strings will work.

Comment: T could be anything. I do not control T because the array part of a generic BTree.

Comment: Then you need something like the answer @NicholasRing presents, with a bit of additional code to handle nested managed type declarations and a test for a tkRecord inside the clone class function.

Comment: Something that tests the nature of T at construction that loads the correct procedural variable with the relevant clone function. Each clone function tuned to a different payload for T.

Comment: I was hoping the RTL would provide me with that. function GetArrayCloneProc<T>: TArrayCloneProc  :-)

Comment: I think you should have a look into Synopse [TDynArray](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=254), which can handle nested records containing dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question on Google+ - https://plus.google.com/u/0/116430453567926016001/posts/b1u1shzkmrW

The code is by Stefan Glienke and I have re-posted the code here with to minor changes to two variable types, so it is 64 bit compatible.

```
uses
  TypInfo,
  SysUtils;

type
  TArray = record
    class function Clone<T>(const source: T): T; static;
  end;

function DynArrayLength(const A: Pointer): NativeInt;
type
  PDynArrayRec = ^TDynArrayRec;
  TDynArrayRec = packed record
  {$IFDEF CPUX64}
    _Padding: LongInt;
  {$ENDIF}
    RefCnt: LongInt;
    Length: NativeInt;
  end;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if A <> nil then
    Result := PDynArrayRec(PByte(A) - SizeOf(TDynArrayRec))^.Length;
end;

{$POINTERMATH ON}
type
  PArray = ^Pointer;
{$POINTERMATH OFF}

procedure CopyArrayDeep(Dest, Source: PArray; TypeInfo: Pointer; Count: NativeInt);
var
  typeData: PTypeData;
  elType: PPTypeInfo;
  i: Integer;
len : NativeInt;
begin
  if (Source = nil) or (Count = 0) then
    Exit;
  typeData := GetTypeData(TypeInfo);
  elType := typeData.elType;
  if (elType <> nil) and (elType^.kind = tkDynArray) then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Count-1 do
    begin
      len := DynArrayLength(Source[i]);
      DynArraySetLength(Dest[i], elType^, 1,@len);
      CopyArrayDeep(Dest[i], Source[i], elType^, len);
    end;
  end
  else
    if elType <> nil then
      CopyArray(Dest, Source, elType^, Count)
    else
      Move(Source^, Dest^, Count * typeData.elSize);
end;

class function TArray.Clone<T>(const source: T): T;
var
  p: PTypeInfo;
  count: NativeInt;
  i: Integer;
begin
  p := TypeInfo(T);
  if p.Kind <> tkDynArray then
    raise ENotSupportedException.Create('type not supported');
  count := DynArrayLength(PArray(@source)^);
  DynArraySetLength(PArray(@Result)^, p, 1,@count);
  CopyArrayDeep(PArray(@Result)^, PArray(@source)^, p, count);
end;﻿
```

Comment: Note in the comments made by @StefanGlienke that it would be possible to expand this to include nested managed types (strings,dynamic arrays etc) as well.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question is "How do I speedup the copy of a generic array" and my answer covers "copy of a generic array" section. It covers the poster's issue of "But that does not play nice with managed types." and "What options do I have?" The only part which isn't cover is the speed up issue but since there is no timing present, I have no idea if is faster or not - I doubt it is since it uses the RTL but that is only a guess on my part. So to me, it relates to the question a lot but doesn't answer the question fully but without timing, how can that be done?

Comment: It doesn't look very much as though the code here is going to be semantically the same as `for i:= 0 to count -1 do D[i]:= S[i];`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Except that `for i:= 0 to count -1 do D[i]:= S[i];` is a shallow copy, while the routine presented does a deep copy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Where does he say that?

Comment: I'm hoping to get something faster than:

for i:= 0 to count -1 do D[i]:= S[i];